# Django - String customizing color for template

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates, django-views

Hey is it possible to customize a text in my view which I output on my template with certain words being in a different colour? For example I have a word which I output to my template:

```
def test(request):
    text = 'test text but this section is red'
    return render(request, 'test.html', {'text':test}
```

How can I get a different colour for 'this section is red' but the rest is normal to show in my template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can achieve this with different approaches.

Django has [`safe`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#safe) filter and [`autoescape`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#autoescape) tag in template.

```
def test(request):
    text = '<span style="color: red">test text but this section is red</span>'
    return render(request, 'test.html', {'text':test}
```

and in template just use;

```
{{ text|safe }}
```

or

```
{% autoescape off %} {{ text }} {% endautoescape %}
```

or you can write your own custom filter with `mark_safe`

```
from django import template
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def custom_filter(text, color):
    safe_text = '<span style="color:{color}">{text}</span>'.format(color=color, text=text)
    return mark_safe(safe_text)
```

and in template;

```
{{ text|custom_filter:'red'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Split it into two so you can differentiate between them in your template.

```
def test(request):
    text = 'test text but'
    red_text = 'this section is red'
    return render(
        request,
        'test.html',
        {'text': text, 'red_text': red_text}
    )
```

Then in the template;

```
<p>{{ text }} <span style="color: red">{{ red_text }}</span></p>
```

Comment: What do I do if the text length is variable and I dont know how long its going to be?

Comment: @Noobfor if that's the case, I'd give the person creating the content the ability to style it how they want with a proper text editor & then you don't need to worry.